# Why this jsfiddle wont run?

Tags: javascript

This is probably a stupid mistake, but I'm new to jsFiddle, and I can't run this piece of code:
[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnG4n/)

The code should put either `OK` or `not ok` in the .output div. It doesn't do it. Thanks

Comment: Not related to jsFiddle. Your code has errors: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } fiddle.jshell.net:57*.

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript error console.

Comment: If you are using chrome, right click on the page, inspect element, then refresh the page, you should see a 1 (x) on the bottom and leftmost part of your browser. If you are on firefox, see http://getfirebug.com/, if you are on IE... switch to ff or chrome.

Comment: You can use Firefox & Firebug (it's an add-on) or Chrome (it comes with its own developer tools) to debug your JS.

Comment: Oh, havn't thought of the browser console. Thought there's a jsFiddle built in thing. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/MbxWG/). Your `curr_year` wasn't a string, and you forgot a `);` at the end.

Comment: Just another tip:  if you select onDomReady from the list in the framework section, it will automatically wrap your code in $(document).ready().  The default is $(window).load().

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things.

Firstly you were missing a closing `)` at the end of the code.

Secondly, you can't get a substring of a date type. You need to convert it to a string first:

http://jsfiddle.net/rnG4n/6/

If you have a look in the Error console in your browser you'll see the problems as they arrise.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- You forgot the enclosing ')' at the end of your javascript to close
  `$(function() {`
- You tried calling substr on curr_year which is a date, not an
  string.

Fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnG4n/4/